# Finding the slope using the implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus

If $F(x,y)=x^2+xy^3$ how can one find the slope of $F(x,y)=2$ at the point where y=1 and x>0 using the implicit function theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy =0$$

and solve for $dy/dx$, evaluating it at the point you want.